# How to access the list of Azure AD Groups using python?

Tags: python, azure, active-directory

I'm new to python. I found the following sample code to retrieve the Azure AD groups from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations#BasicoperationsongroupsGetgroups

the code is:

```
########### Python 3.2 #############
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

# OAuth2 is required to access this API. For more information visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks

headers = {}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
# Specify values for the following required parameters
'api-version': '1.5',
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('graph.windows.net')
    #Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...}) and request body if needed
    conn.request("GET", "/myorganization/groups?%s" % params, "", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

####################################
```

everything is fine but i don't know what would be the value of "headers = {}".

I need help i spent a lot of hours on this but no luck yet.

Comment: Hi @ Kapil Have figured it out how to fetch data from Azure active directory?

Comment: In case anyone else hits this from a search like I did, you might want to check out this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python

Answer (score 2):

Base on my understanding, you need to write the Oauth Authorization information into headers, like the code below:

```
headers = {
    #set your access token
    'Authorization':'your access token'
}
```

Before you accessing the Graph API, you need to get the access token form AD. You can add the authorization information into your headers and request.
About how to get the access token, I suggest that you can refer to this page:
[Active Directory -Authentication Scenarios](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/)