# Retrieving Azure Active Directory and Local Accounts' Data

Tags: python, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating an app that has to show data of an active directory (which is hosted in microsoft azure) i have been told, that this request of data is going to be accomplished by using the Microsoft Graph API through HTTP GET requests.

Apart from “checking” the active directory data in azure, my app has to be capable of read the local accounts’ permissions, so to acomplish that this wouldn’t be possible to be read from the active directory, which means that I will have to check in the computers itself. For that problem, I've been told that I have to do it through powershell programming (to retrieve data of the local accounts).

At the end my application has to run on AWS Lambda.

More than code i would like guys if you can give me an approach of what to use to get to the solution.

**What I have done so far:**

I created a python file with [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849305/how-to-access-the-list-of-azure-ad-groups-using-python) to connect to the microsoft graph API:

There I added a token to access to the graph API, but i couldn't succeed.
I obtained the token from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview), that is supposed to be a sample token of microsoft. For now instead of running my app on AWS Lambda, im running it on pycharm.

My Code on python to access to Azure Active Directory:

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

# OAuth2 is required to access this API. For more information visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer' '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'
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Specify values for the following required parameters
    'api-version': '1.6'})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('graph.windows.net')
    # Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...}) and request body if needed
    conn.request("GET", "/myorganization/groups/f795caea-121d-49c7-8ae6-a95623add8aa?%s" % params, "", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

This is the error I get after executing my code:

```
C:\Users\Joan\PycharmProjects\Prueba\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Joan/PycharmProjects/Prueba/GraphTest.py
b'{"odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_MissingOrMalformed","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Access Token missing or malformed."},"date":"2018-07-02T21:01:26","requestId":"c3429e83-9cee-4f79-bfa5-642aa8da482a","values":null}}'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your header is malformed for authentication as it tells you in the return message.  Add a space between `Bearer` and `<token>`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 hmm it is already added as you can see in my code, or can you give me an example of what you mean? Thank you!

Comment: You have two strings on the same line, so they get concatenated without a space into one long string.  Make them into one string with a space between them and this will correct the error.

Answer (score 2):

This section:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer' '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'
}
```

Requests an additional `space` between `'Bearer'` and the token itself:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' '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'
}
```

I'm assuming this is just some scratch POC code but, just in case, keep in mind that your token *will* expire after 1hr so hardcoding it like this doesn't make sense. You'll want to fetch a new token as needed and inject it into the header when making the call.